# Have a question about $L^p$ multiplier.

Tags: harmonic-analysis

I'm studying $L^p$ multiplier. While reading the book, it says

"The characteristic function of the unit disk is not an $L^p$ multiplier on $\mathbb{R}^n$ when $n\ge2$ unless $p=2$."

How can I verify this? It says it will be discussed in later section 10.1 which does not exist, the book ends at Chapter 5. There is no section 10.1.

Comment: Perhaps you could mention the title of the book.

Comment: It's Classical fourier analysis - Loukas Grafakos 2ed.

Comment: Section 10.1 is [here](http://perso.crans.org/moussa/Grafakos2.pdf)

Comment: The book Classical Fourier Analysis indeed has only 5 chapters. But it has continuation called Modern Fourier Analysis, which [has chapter 10](http://books.google.com/books?id=B-zebZafcLUC&pg=PA339). (Both books belong are from [Graduate Texts in Mathematics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graduate_Texts_in_Mathematics) series.)